# Storage CloudBlob: GetBlobReference returns timeout

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2010, azure-blob-storage

I've a CloudBlob object that verifies if a specific blob exists on a container.
Since I've implemented it, I got no problems, but now I started receiving 'Connection timed out' error.
I took a look to the service and it works fine.

Here is my code:

```cs
            var blob = container.GetBlobReference(string.Format("{0}.{1}", name, estensione));
                var t = blob.ExistsAsync(); // <- Here I get the exception

                t.ContinueWith(ar =>
                {
                    if (ar.Result)
                    {
                        blob.FetchAttributesAsync();

                        if (blob.Properties.Length > 0)
                        {
                            byte[] blobBytes = new byte[blob.Properties.Length];

                            blob.DownloadToByteArrayAsync(blobBytes, 0);
                            return blobBytes;
                        }
                        else
                            return null;
                    }
                }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);

                t.ContinueWith(ar =>
                {
                    Utils.SendCrashes(ar.Exception);  // <-- The exception is handled here
                }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

Exception message: 
One or more errors occurred. (Connection timed out)

Exception details:
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteAsyncInternal[T] (Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.RESTCommand`1[T] cmd, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.RetryPolicies.IRetryPolicy policy, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.OperationContext operationContext, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x01034] in C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\WindowsRuntime\Core\Executor\Executor.cs:311 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlob+<>c__DisplayClass80_0.b__0 () [0x00074] in C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\WindowsRuntime\Blob\CloudBlob.cs:603

Comment: On which line in your code are you getting the exception?

Comment: Maybe this repo can help you: https://github.com/cmatskas/Azure.Storage/blob/master/Azure.Storage/BlobStorageAsync.cs

Comment: @GauravMantri-AIS: I edited my post with the line that thrown the exception.